# express.js limit api access to only pages from the same website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to host my app. I have built a simple api that feeds back json. The url is simple like so: http://websitename.parseapp.com/api/new/1/10. Right now, I have my api publicly visible, but I want to limit the access so only pages from that same domain name can access it only.
How can I achieve this with express.js?

Here is a sample code of what I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

// This is an example of hooking up a request handler with a specific request
// path and HTTP verb using the Express routing API.
app.get('/api/:page/:from/:to', function(req, res) {
  res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
});

// This line is required to make Express respond to http requests.
app.listen();
```

Comment: you can use `req.get('host')` to check if the request is coming from that host. But anyone can spoof that header.

Answer (score 4):

You want to prevent [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is already prevented by `express.js`. To allow it from certain sites you have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (see [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)).

If you create a HTTP request to a different domain that the one you are there must be sent an `Origin` HTTP header including the requesting domain. Based on that the webserver decides wether to respond to the request or not.

**If you want to prevent CORS from all domains but the one the site's hosted on:** *You don't have to do anything.*

If you want to allow it from certain sites, alter the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header to the domain names you want.